# How to apply windowing function before filter in Django

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have these models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ....

class Job(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    payment_status = models.ForeignKey('PaymentStatus')
    cleaner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,...)

class PaymentStatus(models.Model): 
    is_owing = models.NullBooleanField()
```

I need to find out, for each job, how many total owed jobs the parent customer has, but only display those jobs belonging to the current user. The queryset should be something like this:

```
user = self.request.user
queryset = Job.objects.select_related('customer'
    ).filter(payment_status__is_owing=True).annotate(
                num_owings=RawSQL('count(jobs_job.id) over (partition by customer_id)', ())
                                       ).filter(cleaner=user)
```

I am using 'select_related' to display fields from the customer related to the job.

Firstly I haven't found a way to do this without the windowing function/raw SQL.
Secondly, regardless of where I place the .filter(window_cleaner=user) (before or afer the annotate()), the final result is always to exclude the jobs that do not belong to the current user in the total count. I need to exclude the jobs from displaying, but not from the count in the windowing function.
I could do the whole thing as raw SQL, but I was hoping there was a nicer way of doing it in Django.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps and it really depends on how you are wanting to display the results to your user.  However if it were me with a free hand to the design aspect I would probably split my window. Perhaps having the total of owed jobs for the parent customer at the top and a separate list for the jobs that belong to the current user below.  Then I would split the construction of the data doing a normal query, as you have, for the jobs relating to the current user but then use a custom template tag to calculate the total number of jobs for the parent customer.

I use custom template tags quite a bit.  I find they are very cool for those quick snapshot totals that we all want to display to our users.  For example....the total number of points accumulated, the number of outstanding tasks, etc etc.

If you've not looked at them previously check out the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/

They are really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks - with custom template tags I could show the total for each customer on each row, but I guess that means a database query for each row though? That would be prohibitive, I need just one db query/queryset.